# Authenticating Google Cloud Storage Through Command Line?

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-storage

I'd like to use Google Cloud Storage to pull down some files for a project I'm building automatically through Docker. To do this, I'd like to do the authentication entirely through commands without opening browser windows (something like authenticating with a client_id and secret as happens with Amazon's S3). Is this possible? Is there any way to programmatically authenticate for Google Cloud Storage, through gsutil or the API?

Comment: If you're going to downvote, can you explain why?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Service accounts for your application. For more information check the following [link](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/authentication)